# nullPointerException in a MIDLet

Tags: java, java-me, nullpointerexception, midp, midlet

I have written the following `Java Application`:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;


public class JavaApplication6 extends MIDlet
{
private static Form clockForm=null;
private static StringItem clockItem=new StringItem("hello", "World!");
private static ClockTask task=null;
private static Timer timer=null;

static class ClockTask extends TimerTask 
{
private int count=0;
        @Override
public void run()
{
count++;
clockItem.setText("hello "+count);
}
}
public static  void JavaApplication6() throws Exception
{
clockForm=new Form("Clock");
clockItem=new StringItem("","0");
clockForm.append(clockItem);
}

    @Override
public  void startApp()
{
task=new ClockTask();
timer=new Timer();
timer.schedule(task,1000,1000);
Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(clockForm);}

    @Override
public void pauseApp()
{}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional)
{}


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        JavaApplication6 test=new JavaApplication6();
        test.startApp();



    }
}
```

but when I run it, it gives me the following `exception` on the last line of `startApp()`;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.<init>(Display.java:420)
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(Display.java:447)
    at javaapplication6.JavaApplication6.startApp(JavaApplication6.java:42)
    at javaapplication6.JavaApplication6.main(JavaApplication6.java:56)
```

Answer (score 2):

You created static method `JavaApplication6` named as it is the constructor. But it is not. So it is not called when you say `JavaApplication6 test=new JavaApplication6();`. Therefore `clockForm` remains uninitialized, i.e. `null`. So, line

`Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(clockForm);`

throws NPE becuase `clockForm` is `null` at this point.

The solution is to remove `static void` from line `public static  void JavaApplication6() throws Exception`. It should look like

`public JavaApplication6() throws Exception`

In this case it becomes constructor and everything will work.

Good luck.

Comment: still a NPE but this time in a diff part, this time it gives the exception at **clockForm=new Form("Clock")**

Answer (score -3):

You seem to be approaching things in a fundamentally wrong way.

I mean, even if you somehow manage to figure and hack through all of the null pointer exceptions, you will not get a valid MIDlet application code.

Thing is, because **class JavaApplication6 extends MIDlet**, the following line will throw runtime exception at any properly functioning MIDP implementation (read: at any correctly working device):

```
JavaApplication6 test=new JavaApplication6(); // SecurityException in runtime
```

This is the way how things are specified by MIDP ([JSR 118](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=118)) API. Above line means that application attempts to invoke MIDlet constructor bypassing the AMS, which will cause SecurityException in runtime.

This is clearly explained in [MIDlet constructor javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#MIDlet%28%29), note what is stated in `Throws`:

```
protected MIDlet()

    Protected constructor for subclasses. The application management software
    is responsible for creating MIDlets and creation of MIDlets is restricted.
    MIDlets should not attempt to create other MIDlets.

Throws:
    SecurityException - unless the application management software is creating
    the MIDlet.
```

Comment: so you are telling me there is no way to make my application working?

Comment: @user1064929 why? there are tens thousands midlets out there that work just fine. To make your one working just like thousands others, write the correct code. For a start, you can drop `main` with everything that is in there and find a way to get what you need without. Click on `midp` tag under your question to find tutorials if you're interested

Comment: @user1064929 where did you get that tutorial?